# Algorithm to sort a Java List based on the proximity of each object's method call to a goal value?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, comparator

I am trying to recommend opponents for a quiz based game, the metric recorded and to be used for this is the strength value. The strength value = wins / defeats, this is not stored as a property but a method within the Player class.

I have a list of recommended players based on other metrics, but want to sort it by closeness in each object's player.calculateStrengthValue() to a goal value (above or below, so need to make that goal value a relative scale of 0)?

I'm unsure how to do this and though I did attempt to use Comparator:

```
Double strengthScore = player.get().calculateStrengthScore();

//Sort recommended players by strength proximity to user.
Collections.sort(recommendedPlayers, new Comparator<Player>() {

@Override
public int compare(Player o1) {

return new Double(o1.calculateStrengthScore()).compareTo(strengthScore);
}
});
```

As far as I can tell the returned list is still unsorted. When I tried:

```
return new Double(o1.calculateStrengthScore()).compareTo(o2);
```

It did sort them but in ascending order, not relative to the strengthScore variable value.

Edit:

Changed the compareTo to:

```
return new Double(o1.calculateStrengthScore() - strengthScore).compareTo(o2.calculateStrengthScore() - strengthScore);
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide a [*Minimal, Reproducible Example*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: It looks like you're using comparator incorrectly.
From [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare-T-T-), the `compare()` method should return: _a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as the first argument is less than, equal to, or greater than the second._ Your comparator is using Double internally, which is then cast to an int, easy to imagine that wouldn't work like you want.

Comment: @Kaan Thanks, however, when I wrapped it in Integer.valueOf() and cast the types to Integer it still doesn't work, they are just ordered in ascending order.

Comment: Try replacing your approach to not involve double at all. If a double is involved, it’s being forced into an int, which will not do what you want. To see this, you could add a println() to show the comparison result. I bet they’re all 0.

Comment: I might be missing something, perhaps what you're doing should make sense, but we would need to see more code, reproducible example, etc.